# Getting "ImportError: cannot import name string" when trying to run Pylearn2 make_cifar100_whitened.py

Tags: python, pylearn2

When I am trying to run `make_cifar100_whitened.py` inside `Pylearn2/scripts/datasets` I get :

```
G:\pylearn2-master\pylearn2\scripts\datasets>make_cifar100_whitened.py
WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not available, if using conda: `conda install m2w64-toolchain`
WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not detected ! Theano will be unable to execute optimized C-implementations (for both CPU and GPU) and will default to Python implementations. Performance will be severely degraded. To remove this warning, set Theano flags cxx to an empty string.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\pylearn2-master\pylearn2\scripts\datasets\make_cifar100_whitened.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pylearn2.utils import string
ImportError: cannot import name string
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: The [`pylearn2.utils module's repo`](https://github.com/lisa-lab/pylearn2/tree/master/pylearn2/utils) does not contain a `string.py` script. The closest are `string_utils.py`, `common_strings.py` and `bit_strings.py`. Maybe that `make_cifar100_whitened.py` script needs to be edited to fix the imports. Create an issue on github, maybe.

Comment: Thanks, good point.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I found the fix.
the actual import needs to be

```
from pylearn2.utils import string_utils as string
```